# send an email from a plain ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a ruby script where it sends emails to the users. With the rails framework, I am able to send it but can we do it with just plain ruby script

Comment: Shelling to the command line utility `sendmail` would be pretty easy. But have you googled for `ruby smtp` yet?

Comment: you mean Net::Http?

Comment: No; SMTP is the acronym for the outbound email protocol - Simple Mail Transfer Protocol. When asking such a minimal question here, you should be prepared to back up your question with web searches for your topic.

Comment: @philip. Thanks for the information. Yeah, I did but was a little bit confused. I will make sure from next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could shell out to the command line as suggested by Philip. But of course there is also Gem for sending mails: https://github.com/mikel/mail

From the README of this gem:

```
mail = Mail.new do
  from     'me@test.lindsaar.net'
  to       'you@test.lindsaar.net'
  subject  'Here is the image you wanted'
  body     File.read('body.txt')
  add_file :filename => 'somefile.png', :content => File.read('/somefile.png')
end

mail.deliver!
```